# markdown2: using extras : html-classes with a dictionary in php

Tags: php, markdown

I can turn on "tables" like this :

```
echo shell_exec(escapeshellcmd('markdown2 -x tables index.md'));
```

or like his :

```
echo shell_exec(escapeshellcmd('markdown2 --extras=tables index.md'));
```

even this is working correct:

```
echo shell_exec(escapeshellcmd('markdown2 --extras tables index.md'));
```

And I can turn on all extras like this :

```
echo shell_exec(escapeshellcmd('markdown2 --extras="break-on-newline","code-friendly","fenced-code-blocks","footnotes","tables","wiki-tables","strike","use-file-vars","task_list","codehilite"  index.md'));
```

except one :  **html-classes**  [^1](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2/wiki/Extras)
here I need to add a dictionary like this :

```
>> import markdown2
>> classesDict = {'img':'yourclassname'}
>> markdowner  = Markdown(extras={ "html-classes":classesDict })
>> markdowner.convert("*boo!*")
```

And I can't figure out how to add the dictionary to my php command.

Can you please help me ?

Comment: Look into passing a script file as the parameter.

Comment: @GetSet I am afraid I do not understand, can you please elaborate this ?

Comment: Was just a suggestion to further investigate, on whether you can pass in a script file that contains all your params and options. Some research may be necessary.